# extracting version from key value file and replacing in html file in single command

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep

I have a configuration file named configuration.xml which has structure like this:

```
version = "1.0.0"
...
```

I want read the version of the file and replace a place holder (#VERSION#) in a html file named template.html which has structure like this:

```
<div> version: #VERSION# </div>
```

I have tried using grep and sed and successfully done this 2 operation separately but could not combine them together. follow is my 2 commands:

```
grep -Po "(?<=^version ).*" configuration.conf |cut -d "=" -f 2 | cut -d "\"" -f 2)

sed -i "s/#VERSION#/${ver1}/g" "template.html"
```

Can anyone give me a single command for doing this operation?

Comment: where you stored `ver1` ?

Comment: I tried to put these in a bash But I was unsuccessful  too. I was remained from my try to Bashifying ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just save the first command result to a varibale.

```
ver1=$(grep -Po '^version\s*=\s*"\K[^"]*' configuration.conf)
sed -i "s/#VERSION#/$ver1/g" template.html
```

single command would be,

```
sed -i "s/#VERSION#/$(grep -Po '^version\s*=\s*"\K[^"]*' configuration.conf)/g" template.html
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep '^version' configuration.conf | grep -o '\".*\"' | tr -d '\n\"' | xargs -0 -I {} sed 's/#VERSION#/{}/g' 'template.html'
```

P.S.- The grep command you've provided didn't work on my mac because it couldn't understand the '-P' option. So I had to rewrite that in another way.

But the above command should give you the general idea. I tested this and it works for me.